# How to write regex to extract pattern from string

Tags: java, regex, json

I have a JSON string and I want to extract the information I need to care about. What I want  is  to extract the value of the key 'name' from JSON string,  there may be multiple entries of 'name'.

e.g  the JSON string is :

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","name":"allen","detail":{"detailkey1":"detailvalue2","name":"john","detailkey2":"detailvalue2"}}
```

I need to extract 'allen' and 'john' from this JSON String.

I am not familiar with regex and hope someone can help on it.

If you can give sample code in java, that's will be great.

Thanks

Updated: thanks for everybody's reply and I just tried it by myself and actually it's pretty simple.  Copy my code below

```
final String mydata = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\",\"name\":\"allen\",\"detail\":{\"detailkey1\":\"detailvalue2\",\"name\":\"john\",\"detailkey2\":\"detailvalue2\"}}";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"name\":\"(.*?)\"");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Make an attempt, and show your code.

Comment: Find a JSON library and save your sanity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to parse it using any JSON parser. Here's how to do it with Java [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) parser.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name")); // allen

JSONObject detail = jsonObject.getJSONObject("detail");
System.out.println(detail.getString("name")); // john
```

To support multiple names, you'd have an embedded JSON array, instead of repeating the key.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"name\": [\"Mike Ross\", \"Rachel Zane\"]}");
System.out.println(jsonObj.getJSONArray("name").getString(1)); // Rachel Zane
```

Comment: Just have a try by myself and realized it's pretty simple ^_^

Comment: @lorcel Yes, it's pretty simple. If you later feel the need to map JSON to your Java objects take a look at [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Please, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped.